# Arquillian tests with TestNG on wildfly-swarm

Tags: java, testng, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

Is it possible to run arquillian tests through TestNG? Im trying [this tutorial](https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/testing/arquillian.html) here, but it requires the Arquillian testRunner that i can only select with the `@RunWith` annotation from JUnit.

My research showed that there is no equivalent annotation/mechanism in TestNG.

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't done any testing with TestNG so I'm not sure whether what we have would work by just replacing the arquillian-junit-container with the TestNG equivalent.

In theory it's a yes, but not something we've tried. Feel free to give it a go and let us know if there are problems we can fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Arquillian with TestNG - I do not see any issues so far.

Check this site for the sample test - scroll down for the test.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/

You need to extend the `Arquillian` base class to use it with TestNG.

```
@RunAsClient
public class GoogleSearchTest extends Arquillian{

}
```

Comment: The will the `@RunAsClient` annotation cause all test to be ran outside of the container? 
As i experienced it, it is not required to put it on the type-level to enable the TestNG runner in the first place.

Comment: @tuberains , yes , outside the container. I am not saying it is required.

Comment: I rolled back to JUnit because i couldn't get the advertised dependency injection to work.
But as you answered my first question correctly i'll award you...